# Dropdown highlight based on selection from url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown which on change goes to the selected page.  However when that page loads I want the ability to show what page it is on.  For example if someone clicks colorado it will move to that page but the option showing is always the first "See All".  How can I search for what was clicked and then display that on the page?  I know I can use sessions but it is fairly difficult as I am trying to do all of this in sharepoint...

```
 <select name="dropdown" onchange="javascript:location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="...Lists/Events/Events.aspx">See All</option>
<option value="...Lists/Events/Colorado.aspx">Colorado</option>
<option value="...Lists/Events/MidAtlatic%20States.aspx">Mid-Atlantic States</option>
<option value="...Lists/Events/Pacific%20NorthWest.aspx">Pacific Northwest</option>
</select>​
```

Comment: Why javascript? You can do it in .NET as well, reading values from the request object...

Comment: @Mr.White hmmm I am not really familiar with .NET and I thought JS would be the easiest. Ill look into .NET, but would rather stick with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this the following. When the new page load, it would extract the value of the corresponding option from the url and set that value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var pageName = location.pathname.split("/")[url.split("/").length - 1]; 
$('select option').each(function()
{
  if($(this).val().indexOf(pageName) != -1)
     $('select').val($(this).val());   
});

});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/08qyom1a/

Comment: Hmmm this may work for one word options but not Pacific Northwest right?

Comment: It should since the value of the actual pagename is same as the value of the dropdown.

Comment: Nvm I think this will work ill just add: optionName.replace("%20, " ");

Comment: hmm I am having trouble setting the dropdown value if it doesnt correspond to it directly.  I am logging optionName and it may be a little off.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a better solution along with an example. Hopefully that should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Execute it on DOM Ready,

```
$('select[name="dropdown"] option').each(function(){

   var _val = $(this).val().replace("...", ""); // Fetching value and replacing ...

   if(window.location.href.indexOf(_val)!=-1)
      $(this).attr("selected", true);

});
```

Comment: Sorry, without using jquery can I do document.getElementById??